# Counter Example for the union of any number of compact sets is compact in T2-spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

We know that, the intersection of arbitrary many compact sets is compact in Hausdorff Spaces.

I need counter example analogous of above proposition for the union is not true. When I consider, logically it does not have to be compact but I cannot find a counter example in one way or another. Could someone give a counter example please? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider the union of all the singletons in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Expanding: Every noncompact set in a T2 space is a union of compact sets.

Comment: Or to be a little parsimonious use the countably many singletons of integers in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Did you mean one point sets as singletons? Thanks for answer

Comment: @esrabasar : yes.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I ve written it but I need more perceptible example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to all :))

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Better: *every* subset of *every* topological space is a union of compact sets (since singletons are always compact).